# Logistic regression using 2 time points

Tags: logistic, interpretation

I am performing logistic regression and would like some help with interpretation.
My data was collected at 2 time points; baseline and follow-up.

My outcome variable is a psychosocial functioning variable (as an example working or not working) at follow-up.

In step 1 I entered the functioning variable at baseline. In step 2 and 3 I entered a number of covariates e.g sex, age, SES, psychopathology variables (dichotomous).

In step 4 I entered a continuous variable which is the BPD difference score and it is dimensional.

So my problem is with interpretation. If I find that step 4 was significant and BPD difference score significantly predicted "working at time 2". If this was a linear regression I could say that there was an improvement in working as working at baseline was controlled for. But I am unsure of how to interpret it when I control for the dichotomous variable in step 1 (working at baseline) in a logistic regression.

Does that make sense?

I have done the analysis in SPSS.

Thank you for any responses and I apologise for my inexperience and possible simple question, I am trying my hardest to understand it but I cannot manage to figure it out without help.

Answer (score 1):

To translate from the OLS case to the logistic case, you could simply change "improvement in working" to "improvement in the odds of working".

There are a variety of ways to model pre- post- designs, but if you decide to use this one, that's the way to change it.

Comment: Thank you Peter. I much appreciate it and the simplicity of the comment makes perfect sense.